# getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("version.xml") android studio return null

Tags: android, eclipse

```
public static String getVersion(){
    String version = "";
    InputStream input = MyUtils.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("version.xml");
    try {
        HashMap<String,String> data = parseXml(input);
        version =  data.get("version");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.e("dxsversion","version-->"+version);
    return version;
}
```

this code Working properly in Eclipse,but Not working properly at Android studio
the function write at project's library(Android studio's library Module),the version.xml file is at project(Android studio's Main Module), Why?

Comment: Try to use `ResourceBundle properties = ResourceBundle.getBundle("version");`

Comment: it can't working,but thank you all the same!.![mycode][]

Comment: mybe I must get the xml path!my code is like this:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/dt1Ma.jpg

Comment: Did you resolve your issue?  Where did you have to put the file to find it?